# Juju bootstraping gomaasapi timestamp error

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas

Have a simple setup consisting of one LTS 14.04 MAAS server, responsible for dhcp and dns, and a laptop target node. Target node has successfully reached "Ready" state; however, while attempting to bootstrap into maas environment, I get the following error:

```
ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Expired timestamp: given 1400585768 and now 1400610974 has a greater difference than threshold 300)
```

This happens towards the end of bootstrap process, i.e. target node has been update and relevant service have started it:

```
juju -v --debug bootstrap -e maas --upload-tools

...
Setting up libsnappy1 (1.1.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up juju-mongodb (2.4.9-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
tools from http://MAAS_IP.hum.com/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=a5b32a4c-e04c-11e3-8e9d-3c970e523f90&op=get_by_key downloaded: HTTP 200; time 0.229s; size 7356324 bytes; speed 32134911.000 bytes/s 559550d004af5b4c7cee626c6be1b9fae2d2fcac15ce66fb41443eb0a0c8b3df  /var/lib/juju/tools/1.18.3.1-trusty-amd64/tools.tar.gz
tar: FORCE-VERSION: time stamp 2014-05-20 18:29:11 is 24782.564204358 s in the future
tar: jujud: time stamp 2014-05-20 18:29:11 is 24782.252135833 s in the future
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00266961 s, 393 MB/s
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00269804 s, 389 MB/s
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00339052 s, 309 MB/s
juju-db start/running, process 31297
2014-05-20 11:36:08 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:302 running juju-1.18.3.1-trusty-amd64 [gc]
2014-05-20 11:36:08 DEBUG juju.agent agent.go:384 read agent config, format "1.18"
2014-05-20 11:36:08 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:30 opening environment "maas".
2014-05-20 11:36:08 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Expired timestamp: given 1400585768 and now 1400610974 has a greater difference than threshold 300)
2014-05-20 18:36:14 ERROR juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:123 bootstrap failed: rc: 1
Stopping instance...
2014-05-20 18:36:14 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:113 Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
2014-05-20 18:36:14 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:14 destroying environment "maas"
2014-05-20 18:36:15 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 rc: 1
```

Been searching for timestamp keyword with no luck. Rebooting and recommissioning of the target node doesn't seem to help. Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible cause for this might be this http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting.html#possible-cause-timing-issues - i.e. MAAS server's clock is way out of sync compared to the client machine's.

I observed this when using a VM for the MAAS server, which had a snapshot a few days old. Every time I tried to bootstrap after restoring from the snapshot I got the error. The solution was as easy as running `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` to update the server's clock beforehand.

Comment: Indeed. However, I had to do the synchronization manually, date --set ..., my target node cannot access ntp.ubunut.com. (Target has a single nic that's connected to an isolated maas network. The server, though, has 2 nics, with one facing outside.)

Comment: All your nodes should be able to download packages (i.e. have an internet connection and also be able to access ntp.ubuntu.com) from archive.ubuntu.com OR you need to setup a local mirror and configure an APT proxy for juju. See https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/howto-proxies.html for details. You'll need to `apt-get install squid-deb-proxy` package and configure it before juju can use it on your MAAS with nodes on an isolated network. For the time sync issues, similarly you can setup NTP server on your MAAS cluster then nodes can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your own local ntp (net tine server)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=862620

and update your /etc/maas/preseed/preseed-master file to point to your ntp server instead of ntp.ubuntu.com and your are both ocal and don't have to hand crank anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Time zone to UTC, and bootstrap it again, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it came down to my firewall.  I was not letting the NTP through my firewall.  I had to allow UDP/123 through the firewall so the node could sync its time.