# Juju - Unknown error

Tags: juju, maas

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server, have MaaS as Juju environment. I was having some issues which my bootstrapped node couldn't access the charm store, so I installed the squid proxy server.

Here's what I did:

[image]

Default

[image]

Commented

[image]

[image]

Commented the http_access deny_all

Added `http_access allow network`

Added `http_acces allow all`

[image]

Added `acl network src 172.16.1.0/24`

[image]

Juju status

[image]

[image]

The ~/.juju/environments.yaml file:

[image]

`juju debug-log --replay` :

[image]

I don't know why is not working, even the charms WordPress and MySQL are still allocating...

Any tips? Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

On the MaaS Server:

`route -n`

[image]

`tracepath google.com`

[image]

Now `juju ssh 0`:

`route -n`

[image]

`tracepath google.com`

[image]

`curl -v google.com`

[image]

Information about my setup on MaaS Server:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I re-bootstrapped my MaaS environment, deployed mysql+wordpress+relation and deployed juju gui, and this is my actual status, but my wordpress node can't seem to do: `add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers` despite having installed it on my server

[image]

[image]

[image]

Testing `add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers` on my MaaS server:

[image]

Testing `add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers` on the wordpress node ( hook failed install ):

[image]

**EDITED**

`route -n`

[image]

`curl www.google.com`

[image]

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

[image]

`juju resolved --retry wordpress/0`

`juju resolved --retry phpmyadmin/0`

`juju debug-log --replay`

wordpress:

[image]

phpmyadmin:

[image]

[image]

**EDITED**

[image]

`juju ssh 2`

`su`

`cd /var/log/juju`

`export http_proxy=http://root:redeslinux@172.16.1.160:3128/`

`export https_proxy=http://root:redeslinux@172.16.1.160:3128/`

`cat unit-wordpress-0.log`

[image]

[image]

plus `apt-get update`

and did too:

`sudo visudo`

Added **Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"** to the end of the file.

But when I go to my MaaS server where juju is installed:

`juju resolved --retry wordpress/0`

[image]

and so I went again to the node where wordpress is installed to check why is not working:

`juju ssh 2`

`su`

[image]

It works if I add `export http_proxy=http://root:redeslinux@172.16.1.160:3128/`
but when I close the wordpress node PuTTY, and open the MaaS server PuTTY and do  `juju resolved --retry wordpress/0` gives hook failed install.

What to do, to make `export http_proxy=http://root:redeslinux@172.16.1.160:3128/` permanent in the wordpress node or similiar?

**EDITED**

[image]

The bootstrapped node show some messages:

[image]

`juju debug-log --replay`

`machine-0: 2015-05-11 20:13:30 ERROR juju.worker.firewaller firewaller.go:435 failed to lookup "machine-0", skipping port change
machine-0: 2015-05-11 20:13:30 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:219 exited "firewaller": gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Expired timestamp: given 1431375210 and now 1431382411 has a greater difference than threshold 300)
machine-0: 2015-05-11 20:13:31 ERROR juju.provisioner provisioner.go:204 environ provisioner died: failed to process updated machines: failed to get all instances from broker: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Expired timestamp: given 1431375211 and now 1431382412 has a greater difference than threshold 300)
machine-0: 2015-05-11 20:13:31 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:219 exited "environ-provisioner": failed to process updated machines: failed to get all instances from broker: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Expired timestamp: given 1431375211 and now 1431382412 has a greater difference than threshold 300)
machine-0: 2015-05-11 20:13:33 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:219 exited "firewaller": gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Expired timestamp: given 1431375213 and now 1431382414 has a greater difference than threshold 300)`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by charm store you are referring to the website? I'm almost sure that Squid is overkill.

I see that machine 0 uses your proxy successfully. I can also see that the default route of machine 0 is 172.16.1.1, but the default route of the MAAS host is 172.16.1.2. It is set up incorrectly in the MAAS web interface, as you show in your screenshot. Change the "Router" configuration in the MAAS DHCP website to 172.16.1.2, and re-try

Comment: I think not. How do I configure that?

Comment: @Mario You should not have to set up a squid server, it should work magically. So something else must be configured incorrectly in your setup. My first guess was that you use some proxy settings on the host that are re-used for the new node. Please provide more information on the network setup. In particular, let me know if you can ssh into machine-0, in that case just show us the output of `route -n`  and  `tracepath google.com`, check if you can `curl -v google.com` or similar.

Comment: Added more info about the setup.

Comment: I changed the router ip to 172.16.1.2 and it still gives the ppa:charmers/charm-helpers error because it cannot add the ppa, any tips?

Comment: @Mario Can you please rerun `route -n` on machine-0 and check if the route is updated now? If it is, are you still using the proxy when doing `curl www.google.com` on machine-0?  What is the result of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`?

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: @Mario thanks. It's really hard to pin down what the problem could be. Did you try `sudo -E`  as suggested in http://askubuntu.com/questions/452595/cannot-add-ppa-behind-proxy-ubuntu-14-04 ? you could also check the root https proxy settings with `sudo curl -v https://www.google.com` or similar

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: @Mario how about adding the https_proxy to the environments.yaml? I think you only have the http_proxy there so far. There are also apt-specific proxy settings: https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/howto-proxies

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: @Mario that is now a time-related error. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` is suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/465508/juju-bootstrap-debug-failed-to-connect-https-streams-canonical-com
`ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` is suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/469778/juju-bootstraping-gomaasapi-timestamp-error

Answer (score 0):

I had same error check your time zone and set all to UTC, after installation you can return it back in any local time zone